# Creating a socket to a remote HTTP Server using android emulator

Tags: android, sockets, emulation

I'm very new to android programming. I have a program that uses sockets to connect to a remote host, spoof an http request, and parse the results.  For some reason, my socket cannot connect to the host.  I have tested the program in a standalone environment and it connects and works fine.  I went ahead and isolated the function I needed and included it in my activity class to call it that way.  Ive also tried calling it staticly, as well as executing` an asynchronous object and calling it from there.  The internet on my android emulator works from the browser, and i've added the

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

To my android manifest. The code below shows where I stand right now.  What do do I need to do?

```
public class FlightNumResults extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("input"); //if it's a string you stored.
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("HULLO");
    System.out.println(value);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);

    Log.i("Excecution", "Complete");
    Hashtable<String, String> table = flightNumInfo(value);
    if (table == null)
        System.out.println("NULL");

    TableLayout results = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resultTable);

    TableRow rowLabels = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow rowResults = new TableRow(this);
    rowLabels.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.span = 4;

    //Column 1
    TextView destLabel = new TextView(this);  
    destLabel.setText("Destination");  
    destLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);  
    TextView destResult = new TextView(this);  
    destResult.setText(table.get("destination"));  
    destResult.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  

    rowLabels.addView(destLabel);  
    rowResults.addView(destResult);
    //Column 2
    TextView gateLabel = new TextView(this);  
    destLabel.setText("Gate");  
    destLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);  
    TextView gateResult = new TextView(this);  
    destResult.setText(table.get("gate"));  
    destResult.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  

    rowLabels.addView(gateLabel);  
    rowResults.addView(gateResult);
  //Column 3
    TextView scheduledLabel = new TextView(this);  
    destLabel.setText("Scheduled");  
    destLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);  
    TextView scheduledResult = new TextView(this);  
    destResult.setText(table.get("scheduled"));  
    destResult.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  

    rowLabels.addView(scheduledLabel);  
    rowResults.addView(scheduledResult);
  //Column 4
    TextView estimatedLabel = new TextView(this);  
    destLabel.setText("estimated");  
    destLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);  
    TextView estimatedResult = new TextView(this);  
    destResult.setText(table.get("scheduled"));  
    destResult.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  

    rowLabels.addView(estimatedLabel);  
    rowResults.addView(estimatedResult);

    results.addView(rowLabels);
    results.addView(rowResults);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flightnum_results);





}
public Hashtable<String, String> flightNumInfo(String flightNum) {

    Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    System.out.println("Initializing socket");
    try {
        String request = "GET /flifo/servlet/DeltaFlifo?airline_code=DL&flight_number="
                + flightNum
                + "&flight_date="
                + DateCalc.getSlashDateAndTime()
                + "&request=main&DptText=ATL HTTP/1.1";

        Socket conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("www.delta.com"), 80);
        System.out.println("initialized");
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.println(request);
        wr.println("Host: www.delta.com");
        wr.println("Referer: http://www.delta.com/flifo/servlet/DeltaFlifo?airline_code=DL&request=main");
        wr.println("Connection: close\n");
        wr.flush();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
        String myResp = new String();
        String ans = new String();

        do {
            ans = in.nextLine();
            myResp += ans;
        } while (ans.indexOf("<span class=\"detailsLabel\"><br />") < 0);

        wr.close();
        in.close();
        // System.out.println(myResp);
        Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile("<td class=\"tableCell\" align=\"left\">&nbsp;\\s+Atlanta\\s+"
                        + "<a href=\"/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/airports/atlanta.html\">"
                        + "<!-- mp_trans_disable_start -->\\(ATL\\)<!-- mp_trans_disable_end --></a>\\s+<br />&nbsp;(.*?)"
                        + "<br />&nbsp; Gate <!-- mp_trans_disable_start -->([A-Z0-9]{2,3})<!-- mp_trans_disable_end -->\\s+"
                        + "</td>\\s+<td class=\"tableCell\">\\s+&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9:]{6,9})<br />\\s+&nbsp;(.*?)</td>\\s+"
                        + "<td class=\"tableCell\">\\s+&nbsp;([a-z0-9*?:]{6,9}|[a-zA-Z\\s]{6,9})<br />\\s+&nbsp;(.*?)</td>\\s+" 
                        + "<td class=\"tableCell\">&nbsp;(.*?)\\(([A-Z]{3})\\)");


        Matcher m = p.matcher(myResp);
        if (m.find()) {
            table.put("number", flightNum);
            table.put("gate", m.group(2));
            table.put("scheduled", m.group(3));
            table.put("estimated", m.group(5));
            table.put("destination", m.group(8));

            return table;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Here is what my code looks like using AsyncTask.

```
public class FlightNumResults extends Activity {

public String flightNum;
public Hashtable<String, String> table;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    flightNum = intent.getStringExtra("input"); // if it's a string you
                                                // stored.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("HULLO");
    // System.out.println(value);

    setContentView(R.layout.loading);

    Log.i("Excecution", "Complete");
    FlightInfo fi = new FlightInfo();
    fi.execute();
    fi.flightNumInfo(flightNum);
    // Hashtable<String, String> table = fi.flightNumInfo(value);

    // System.out.println(table.get("destination"));

    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_flightnum_results);



}

public class FlightInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Socket conn;
    public PrintWriter wr;
    public DataInputStream dis;
    public DataOutputStream dos;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
             conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("www.delta.com"), 80);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("AsyncTank", "Can't create socket");
        }
        if (conn.isConnected()){
            try {
                dis = (DataInputStream)conn.getInputStream();
                dos = (DataOutputStream)conn.getOutputStream();
                Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Socket created, Streams assigned");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot assign Streams, Socket not connected");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot assign Streams, Socket is closed");
        }
        return null;

        }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute: Completed with an Error.");

        } else {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute: Completed.");

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flightnum_results);

    }



        public  void flightNumInfo(String flightNum) {

              table = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                String request = "GET /flifo/servlet/DeltaFlifo?airline_code=DL&flight_number="
                        + flightNum
                        + "&flight_date="
                        + DateCalc.getSlashDateAndTime()
                        + "&request=main&DptText=ATL HTTP/1.1";

                //Socket conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("www.delta.com"), 80);

                wr = new PrintWriter(dos);

                wr.println(request);
                wr.println("Host: www.delta.com");
                wr.println("Referer: http://www.delta.com/flifo/servlet/DeltaFlifo?airline_code=DL&request=main");
                wr.println("Connection: close\n");
                wr.flush();

                Scanner in = new Scanner(dis);
                String myResp = new String();
                String ans = new String();

                do {
                    ans = in.nextLine();
                    myResp += ans;
                } while (ans.indexOf("<span class=\"detailsLabel\"><br />") < 0);

                wr.close();
                in.close();

                // System.out.println(myResp);
                Pattern p = Pattern
                        .compile("<td class=\"tableCell\" align=\"left\">&nbsp;\\s+Atlanta\\s+"
                                + "<a href=\"/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/airports/atlanta.html\">"
                                + "<!-- mp_trans_disable_start -->\\(ATL\\)<!-- mp_trans_disable_end --></a>\\s+<br />&nbsp;(.*?)"
                                + "<br />&nbsp; Gate <!-- mp_trans_disable_start -->([A-Z0-9]{2,3})<!-- mp_trans_disable_end -->\\s+"
                                + "</td>\\s+<td class=\"tableCell\">\\s+&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9:]{6,9})<br />\\s+&nbsp;(.*?)</td>\\s+"
                                + "<td class=\"tableCell\">\\s+&nbsp;([a-z0-9*?:]{6,9}|[a-zA-Z\\s]{6,9})<br />\\s+&nbsp;(.*?)</td>\\s+" 
                                + "<td class=\"tableCell\">&nbsp;(.*?)\\(([A-Z]{3})\\)");


                Matcher m = p.matcher(myResp);
                if (m.find()) {
                    table.put("number", flightNum);
                    table.put("gate", m.group(2));
                    table.put("scheduled", m.group(3));
                    table.put("estimated", m.group(5));
                    table.put("destination", m.group(8));


                }




        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is common, you are trying to perform some long running operation on the 
main thread of your application.

What that means, is that the main thread is in charge of updating the UI, to enforce a smooth experience, if android detects you are doing some long running operation that is going to be blocking, it will force shutdown the app, to let you know that this is bad.

There are many alternative solution, such as AsynTask, or IntentService.

Also, to establish the socket connection you should do:

```
conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(new URL("http://www.delta.com").getHost()), 80);
dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: I tried using AsyncTask. I updated my question showing how I used it.  what still seems to be the issue?

Comment: I have fixed you currently code, please see my updated answer. Please accept if it fixes your issue.